# Android Facebook SDK - errors when importing SDK

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to import the android Facebook SDK as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).
After importing the project appears, but it shows the following errors:

> The import android.annotation cannot be resolved

and

> The import com.facebook.android.BuildConfig cannot be resolved

I'm using Eclipse Helios, and the virtual devices displayed in the SDK Manager are 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.3 and 3.1 (the guide states `You'll need to have the Android 2.2 (API 8) components installed in order to use the Facebook SDK`). The compiler level displayed in Preferences -> Java Compiler is 1.6.

What could be the problem and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

try

import-> Android-> Existing Android code into workspace

rather than

General-> Existing project into workspace

Answer (score 0):

Not only sample projects in workspace, you may also need to import one more project ..$HOME\facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0\facebook in workspace. 
Hope this will be help.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the Facebook folder not the root.